# Reading double with fscanf on both english and french LANG

Tags: c, internationalization, double, scanf, french

I have an issue with the portability of my code between french and english computers. Indeed, english uses point to separate double, as french uses comma.
The problem is that I can't read a number written in english (with a point) on a french computer, because it expects a comma.

What's the good way to do it ?

I though about making a french and an english file, but I think a better solution should exist

My code for the line with the double is actually :

```
errcd *= fscanf(file, "%lf\n", &N->biais1->l[i]);
```

Comment: Note this is not a English vs. French issue, but a `','` vs. `'.'` for the decimal mark. [Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could read the number in as a character string and then convert it to a double....

```
int n;
double N;
char dummy[100];
fscanf("%s",dummy);
for (n=0;n<100;n++) 
{ /* here you need to make a conversion , to . (or . to ,) */
   if (dummy[n]==',') dummy[n]='.';
   if (dummy[n]==\0) break;
}
N = atof(dummy);
```

Comment: I do like the simplicity of this approach - very good if OP's requirements are only to scan a `.'` vs. `,` string.

Comment: @chux your *locale* approach is amazing... but I worked in France and never came across this as an issue, but then I was not coding in France

Comment: je suis super content que ca marche pour vous - il n'y a pas de quoi, et merci pour l'acceptance de la reponse.

Answer (score 1):

Change *locale*.

Some pseudo-code to get you started.

```
#include <locale.h>  

get current locale  (`*localeconv()`)
for each line
  read line into buffer.
  convert using `strtod()`
  if it fails to convert and has a trailing character
    switch(failing character)
      '.'  : set locale to English (`setlocale()`) and try again
      ','  : set locale to French and try again
restore original locale
```

---

Something like:

```
char *locale_original = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
char *locale_english = ...;
char *locale_french = ...;

char buf[100];
size_t i = 0;
while (i < max && fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) != NULL) {
  char *endptr;
  N->biais1->l[i] = strtod(buf, &endptr);
  if (endptr != buf) {
    switch (*endptr) {
      case '.':  locale_original = setlocale(LC_ALL, locale_english); break;
      case ',':  locale_original = setlocale(LC_ALL, locale_english); break;
      default:
        handle_error();
        break;
    }
    N->biais1->l[i] = strtod(buf, &endptr);
    if (*endptr) {
      handle_error();
      break;
    }
  }
}
setlocale(LC_ALL, locale_original);
```

---

Using *locale* is the standard way to handle variation on different numeric formats.  Unfortunately the standard functions are not that complete.